# Mark jenkins build as unstable

Tags: jenkins, testng, maven-surefire-plugin

My build is marked as failed even if only one test case failed.
I'd like to have it unstable in that case.
As I read it depends on plugin used for execution of build.
At Jenkins wiki I found also something like this:

> A build is unstable if it was built successfully and one or more
> publishers report it unstable. For example if the JUnit publisher is
> configured and a test fails then the build will be marked unstable.

I used maven surefire plugin with HTMLReporter as publisher:

```
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <testFailureIgnore>false</testFailureIgnore>
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>src\test\java\testCases\scenarios\${tests}</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
                <properties>
                    <property>
                        <name>usedefaultlisteners</name>
                        <value>false</value>
                    </property>
                    <property>
                        <name>listener</name>
                        <value>org.uncommons.reportng.HTMLReporter, org.uncommons.reportng.JUnitXMLReporter</value>
                    </property>
                </properties>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <skip>false</skip>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```